# Powershell: Format-Table -Autosize loses the variable values

Tags: powershell

Using POSH 3.0, as a quick example, if I populate an array and try to display the results with FT -Autosize, I can't access the variable after that anymore.  There are quite a few properties to display so -autosize is important to utilize the whole width.

```
$x | Select @{E={$_.AID};L="Action"},@{E={$_.ID};L="SSN"}... | `
    FT -AutoSize
}

#Now the object is no longer accessible
$x | ForEach {
    $_
}
```

So my goal is to view the results in a nicely formatted way, while also keeping the values accessible in the variable.  I had tried to make a copy of the variable, one to view the results and the other to proceed with the values in the variable, but same thing.

Anyone have any good thoughts about this?  Thanks!

Better example:

```
    [array]$recs= Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server `
    -Database $db `
    -InputFile 'c:\sqlquery.sql'
    $arrRecs = @()

ForEach ($record in $recs) {
    $newObjectRecs = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ 
        "todaysDate" = $_.TodaysDate
        "cats" = $record.cats
        "dogs" = $record.dogs
        "surname" = $record.surname
        "givenName" = $record.givenName }

        $arrRecs += $newObjectRecs
}

    $arrRecs | `
    Select @{E={$_.cats};L="cats"},@{E={$_.dogs};L="dogs"},@{E={$_.TodaysDate};L="Date"},surname,givenName | `
        Format-Table -AutoSize

$arrRecs | ForEach {
    $_
    Write-Host "---------"
}

$arrRecs
```

As an update to a comment earlier, if I iterate through the ForEach statement below when trying to display to the screen, it won't display the current item in the pipe, but when it gets to the end of the array, it displays all the items that were in the array.

If I comment out Format-Table -Autosize, it displays the current item in the pipe as expected.

Comment: What are you expecting `$x` to be after the first line? The original objects, or the result of the `select-object` in that pipeline?

Comment: In the first lines, I'm expecting a formatted view of $x.  Trying to change/shorten the labels to fit into the width of the window.  And then I wanted to continue accessing $x.

Comment: So you're expecting `$x` to be unchanged, and it's being changed? I don't think I've ever seen such a thing. Can you show more of the script?

Comment: So after a closer look in the ForEach statement, it's not displaying the current item in the pipe leading me to believe it's no longer accessible.  On its last iteration through the loop, it dumps each item in the array out to the display.  I had been stopping it once I didn't see the current item.  If I comment out FT -Autosize, it loops through displaying each item in the pipe.

Comment: In your updated example, `$arrRecs` is only being populated with the *last* iteration of the loop because `$arrRecs += $newObjectRecs` is outside the `foreach` loop. You also have a syntax error, the closing `}` after that line does not have a corresponding `{`. Is this how it is in your real script too, or is it only your example that's broken?

Comment: Sorry, that was a type-o.  I still find formatting a tad difficult on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of hack-around (yes, I made up a hyphenated word, but I liked it so you have to live with it) you could try pumping `$x` through a `ForEach` and creating a custom object for each record in $x. Something like:

```
$x | %{[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        "Action"=$_.AID
        "SSN"=$_.ID
        "Taco"=$_.FishBeefOrChicken
        "More"=$_.OtherProperties
    }}| FT -Auto
```

While the script you show should not alter $x at all, and $x should be both intact and accessible afterwards, sometimes all it takes to work through a problem is a new perspective and a different method of doing things to find the error that's eluding us.